# Including parameter value with ampersand in Telerik href URL

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, url, radgrid

I have a issue with symbols in account code which I am trying to create the URL using `a href` as below. In my view I am trying to pass an id to my controller using Telerik grid.

```
.Template(x => Html.ActionLink("Month Ends", "MonthEndDates", new { id = x.Account, group = x.Group }))
       .ClientTemplate("<a href=\"MonthEndDates?id=<#= Account #>&group=<#= Group #>\">" + "Month Ends" + "</a>")
```

The problem arises when I have a account code like `APPLA&D`: the id is passed as `APPLA` (missing the `&D`).

How would one go about solving this issue?
I assume you cannot do this in `a href` as `&` cannot be a value in a URL?

Comment: I think you might be bumping into a limitation of HTML, since it uses the ampersand `&` to group parameters. You should restrict the account codes in your database to legal values.

Comment: Try a .Replace("&", "&#38;") (c# function) on the account name before rendering it to the HTML

Comment: Wondering if we can do a if statement and a string compare?

Answer (score 0):

Encode the URL parameters. Untested (since I don't have Telerik available these days):

```
.Template(x => Html.ActionLink("Month Ends", "MonthEndDates", new {
            id = Net.WebUtility.UrlEncode(x.Account),
            group = x.Group
        }))
    .ClientTemplate("<a href=\"MonthEndDates?id=<#= id #>&group=<#= group #>\">" + "Month Ends" + "</a>")
```

This assumes `ClientTemplate` is substituting in the `id` and `group` properties from the anonymous object.